# golang dynamic progressbar

Tags: go, progress-bar

I'm trying file download with golang.

I'm downloading file it's okay. After I'm using cheggaaa's progressbar library. But I can't dynamic.

How can I do dynamic progressbar?

My code below:

package main

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "github.com/cheggaaa/pb"
    "time"
)

/*
    usage = usage text
    version = current number
    help use Sprintf
    *cliUrl from cmd
    *cliVersion from cmd
    *cliHelp * from cmd
*/
var (
    usage      = "Usage: ./gofret -url=http://some/do.zip"
    version    = "Version: 0.1"
    help       = fmt.Sprintf("\n\n  %s\n\n\n  %s", usage, version)
    cliUrl     *string
    cliVersion *bool
    cliHelp    *bool
)

func init() {
    /*
        if *cliUrl != "" {
            fmt.Println(*cliUrl)
        }

        ./gofret -url=http://somesite.com/somefile.zip
        ./gofret -url=https://github.com/aligoren/syspy/archive/master.zip
    */
    cliUrl = flag.String("url", "", usage)

    /*
        else if *cliVersion{
            fmt.Println(flag.Lookup("version").Usage)
        }

        ./gofret -version
    */
    cliVersion = flag.Bool("version", false, version)

    /*
        if *cliHelp {
            fmt.Println(flag.Lookup("help").Usage)
        }

        ./gofret -help
    */
    cliHelp = flag.Bool("help", false, help)
}

func main() {

    /*
        Parse all flags
    */
    flag.Parse()

    if *cliUrl != "" {
        fmt.Println("Downloading file")

        /* parse url from *cliUrl */
        fileUrl, err := url.Parse(*cliUrl)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        /* get path from *cliUrl */
        filePath := fileUrl.Path

        /*
            seperate file.
            http://+site.com/+(file.zip)
        */
        segments := strings.Split(filePath, "/")

        /*
            file.zip filename lenth -1
        */
        fileName := segments[len(segments)-1]

        /*
            Create new file.
            Filename from fileName variable
        */
        file, err := os.Create(fileName)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        /*
            check status and CheckRedirect
        */
        checkStatus := http.Client{
            CheckRedirect: func(r *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
                r.URL.Opaque = r.URL.Path
                return nil
            },
        }

        /*
            Get Response: 200 OK?
        */
        response, err := checkStatus.Get(*cliUrl)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic(err)
        }
        defer response.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println(response.Status) // Example: 200 OK

        /*
            fileSize example: 12572 bytes
        */
        fileSize, err := io.Copy(file, response.Body)
        /*
            progressbar worked after download :(
        */
        var countSize int = int(fileSize/1000)
        count := countSize
        bar := pb.StartNew(count)
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            bar.Increment()
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        }
        bar.FinishPrint("The End!")

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }


        fmt.Printf("%s with %v bytes downloaded", fileName, count)

    } else if *cliVersion {
        /*
            lookup version flag's usage text
        */
        fmt.Println(flag.Lookup("version").Usage)
    } else if *cliHelp {
        /*
            lookup help flag's usage text
        */
        fmt.Println(flag.Lookup("help").Usage)
    } else {
        /*
            using help's usage text for handling other status
        */
        fmt.Println(flag.Lookup("help").Usage)
    }
}
```

While the my program is running:

```
Downloading file
200 OK
```

After download working progressbar:

```
6612 / 6612 [=====================================================] 100.00 % 7s
The End!
master.zip with 6612 bytes downloaded
```

My progressbar code below:

```
/*
    progressbar worked after download :(
*/
var countSize int = int(fileSize/1000)
count := countSize
bar := pb.StartNew(count)
for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
    bar.Increment()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
}
bar.FinishPrint("The End!")
```

How can I solve progressbar problem?

Comment: you're downloading the file before you even start the progress bar.

Comment: @JimB I'm tried but not working because I get fileSize undefined error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More goroutines is not needed. Just read from bar

```
// start new bar
bar := pb.New(fileSize).SetUnits(pb.U_BYTES)
bar.Start()
// create proxy reader
rd := bar.NewProxyReader(response.Body)
// and copy from reader
io.Copy(file, rd)
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the below stuff, and it's right in the general case, unrelated to progressbar, but this library is *exactly* designed to handle this problem, has specialized support for it, and gives an [explicit example of downloading a file](https://github.com/cheggaaa/pb/blob/master/example/copy/copy.go).

---

You need to run the download in parallel with updating the progressbar, currently you're downloading the whole file and then updating the progressbar.

This is a little sloppy, but should get you going in the right direction:

First, grab the expected filesize:

```
    filesize := response.ContentLength
```

Then start your download in a goroutine:

```
    go func() {
        n, err := io.Copy(file, response.Body)
        if n != filesize {
            log.Fatal("Truncated")
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
        }
    }()
```

Then update your progressbar as it goes along:

```
    countSize := int(filesize / 1000)
    bar := pb.StartNew(countSize)
    var fi os.FileInfo
    for fi == nil || fi.Size() < filesize {
        fi, _ = file.Stat()
        bar.Set(int(fi.Size() / 1000))
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    }
    bar.FinishPrint("The End!")
```

Like I say, this is a little sloppy; you probably want to scale the bar better depending on the size of the file, and the `log.Fatal` calls are ugly. But it handles the core of the issue.

Alternately, you can do this without a goroutine just by writing your own version of `io.Copy`. Read a block from `response.Body`, update the progress bar, and then write a block to `file`. That's arguably better because you can avoid the sleep call.

Comment: That works! Thank you. Now source code on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/aligoren/9426249fa8cd04c4633e

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can implement progress bar by yourself with below piece of code.

```
func (bar *Bar) Play(cur int64) {
 bar.cur = cur
 last := bar.percent
 bar.percent = bar.getPercent()
 if bar.percent != last && bar.percent%2 == 0 {
   bar.rate += bar.graph
 }
 fmt.Printf("\r[%-50s]%3d%% %8d/%d", bar.rate, bar.percent, bar.cur, bar.total)
}
```

The key here is to use escape **\r** which will replace the current progress with updated one in place  which creates a dynamic effect.

A detailed explanation can be found at [here](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1596946473-A-simple-example-on-implementing-progress-bar-in-GoLang).